# Excel COM paste not working - Unable to get the Paste property of the Worksheet class

Tags: excel, powershell, com

I am using the following code to paste values from one sheet to another. It used to work but after migrating to EXCEL 2013 stopped working with error "Unable to get the Paste property of the Worksheet class"

```
$excelFrom = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application    
$excelFrom.visible = $false
$excelFrom.DisplayAlerts = $false


$excelTo = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application  
$excelTo.visible = $false
$excelTo.DisplayAlerts = $false





$excelFrom.Workbooks.OpenText("inputfile.xls")
$worksheetFrom = $excelFrom.Worksheets.Item(1)



$excelTo.Workbooks.OpenText("templatefile.xlsx")
$worksheetTo = $excelTo.Worksheets.Item(1)

write-host $worksheetTo.cells[1][2].text

$lastRow1 = $worksheetFrom.UsedRange.rows.count - 11
$lastRow2 = $lastRow1 + 1

#copy account numbers
$worksheetFrom.activate()
$range1 = $worksheetFrom.Range("B15:B17")
$range1.copy()


$worksheetTo.activate()
$range2 = $worksheetTo.Range("A2:A4")
write-host $range2.rows.count
$worksheetTo.Paste($range2)

$excelFrom.quit()
while([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelFrom)){} 
Remove-Variable excelFrom

$excelTo.quit()
while([System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelTo)){}   
Remove-Variable excelTo
```

Comment: What if you do `$worksheetTo.Cells(1, 1).Paste($range2)` ?

Comment: Getting Method invocation failed because [System.__ComObject] does not contain a method named 'Paste'. error

Comment: $range2 = $worksheetTo.Range("A2:A4").Paste this doesn't give error but does nothing either

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone I had to use this -

$worksheetTo.Range("A2:A$lastRow2").Value2 = $worksheetFrom.Range("B15:B$lastRow1").Value2

It seems .Value doesn't work if we are copying from an xls file to xlsx –